# Toggle treating warnings as errors when deploying a shiny app on Heroku via Docker

Tags: r, docker, heroku, shiny, golem

How do I tell either R or Docker or Heroku to **not** treat warnings as errors when deploying a shiny/golem app?

I think last week I already found the answer - something along the lines of `ENV WARNINGS_ARE_ERRORS=false` in my Dockerfile - but I seem to be unable to "re-find" it as my Google game is failing me completely today ;-)

Some key resources:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/golem/vignettes/c_deploy.html
- https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r

This is what my Dockerfile structurally looks like

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0.4
ENV WARNINGS_ARE_ERRORS=false
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  git-core libcurl4-openssl-dev libgit2-dev libicu-dev libpq-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev make pandoc pandoc-citeproc && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "options(repos = c(CRAN = 'https://cran.rstudio.com/'), download.file.method = 'libcurl')" >> /usr/local/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site
RUN R -e 'install.packages("remotes")'
RUN R -e 'remotes::install_github("r-lib/remotes", ref = "97bbf81")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("shiny",upgrade="never", version = "1.5.0")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("golem",upgrade="never", version = "0.2.1")'

[...]

RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_github("rappster/confx")'
RUN mkdir /build_zone
ADD . /build_zone
WORKDIR /build_zone
RUN R -e 'remotes::install_local(upgrade="never")'
CMD R -e "options('shiny.port'=$PORT,shiny.host='0.0.0.0');mypkg::run_app()"
```

And this is the warning that is bumped up to an error that I'm getting:

```
[...]

Step 25/30 : RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_github("rappster/confx")'
 ---> Running in f50d3dd800cb
Downloading GitHub repo rappster/confx@master
valid (NA -> 3f09feea8...) [GitHub]
Downloading GitHub repo rappster/valid@master
Running `R CMD build`...
* checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpKWNYfH/remotes77dbc946c/rappster-valid-3f09fee/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘valid’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building ‘valid_0.0.0.9001.tar.gz’
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘valid’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (valid)
Running `R CMD build`...
* checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpKWNYfH/remotes76bee127a/rappster-confx-e53517f/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘confx’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* installing the package to process help pages
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building ‘confx_0.0.0.9024.tar.gz’
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘confx’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning: replacing previous import ‘magrittr::set_names’ by ‘purrr::set_names’ when loading ‘confx’
** help
Error : (converted from warning) /tmp/RtmpqApPd2/R.INSTALL11445cdd308/confx/man/grapes-not-in-grapes.Rd: \name should not contain !, | or @
ERROR: installing Rd objects failed for package ‘confx’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/confx’
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpKWNYfH/file75a06ee6c/confx_0.0.0.9024.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
Calls: <Anonymous> ... with_rprofile_user -> with_envvar -> force -> force -> i.p
Execution halted
The command '/bin/sh -c Rscript -e 'remotes::install_github("rappster/confx")'' returned a non-zero code: 1
 ▸    Error: docker build exited with Error: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

After stepping through my search history one page at a time I was able to piece it together again.

Turns out the issue is caused by [`{remotes}`](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes) and can be remedied by adding

```
ENV R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS=true
```

to your Dockerfile (see related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/403))

Adding the env var

```
R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS=TRUE
```

to your `.Renviron` file might also work, but didn't test yet.